# C++ friend function does not work (with multiple header and source files)

Tags: c++

I have tried to find a solution in the internet,but I have always found examples where the classes, main function,etc are written in one file, not separated. Maybe it would be enough,but I am new in C++ and I guess my problem is different,because I use different header and source files for each classes and a different source file for main().
So, the problem is: I have tried to make printBoxMeretek(Box) function in Box2 class to be the friend function of Box class. It doesn't work and I don't know why. When I make the whole Box2 class to be friend of Box class, everything is ok. What should I do, if I want only printBoxMeretek(Box) function to be friend,not the whole Box2 class?
Anyway,the error message says that the problem is that boxSzelesseg and boxMagassag variables in Box class are private. But as I know a friend function should be able to handle private variables.
Here are the contents of my test files:
Box.h

```
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

class Box
{
    //friend function from Box2 [can be written anywhere: in private, in public,etc section] =>It does NOT work...why???
    friend void printBoxMeretek(Box);

    //make the whole Box2 class friend =>It works well.
//    friend class Box2;

    public:
};

#endif // BOX_H
```

Box2.h

```
#ifndef BOX2_H
#define BOX2_H

#include <iostream>
#include <Box.h>

class Box2
{
    public:
        void printBoxMeretek(Box)
        { }
};

#endif // BOX2_H
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you cut this down to a [mcve] please

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: ok,I have tried to shorten them.

Comment: @Colossus As you  are a new user, I permitted myself to minimize your example for you, i. e. dropping *any* irrelevant details (such as member variables), just leaving the (yet bad) friend declaration and the other class' function in question. this is all that is needed to reproduce the problem. Hope this helps you asking better questions in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
friend void printBoxMeretek(Box);
```

This declares a *free* function being friend of Box. You want a *member* function being friend, so you should declare a such:

```
class Box2;
class Box
{
    friend void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box);
};
```

Now problem is, you need the complete class declaration available for, so:

```
class Box;
class Box2;
{
public:
    void printBoxMeretek(Box);
};

class Box
{
    friend void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box);
};
```

It does not matter if you have this in the same header or within two of them – the problem remains (i. e. you need to include Box2.h from Box.h).

Side note (thanks, Martin, for clarification): Even though a function is declared using `Box` class, the complete definition of the class only needs to be available when you either *define* or *call* the function, so this works fine as it is. You just have to make sure to include both headers wherever you do one of these (or just always Box.h, which comes with Box2.h implicitly).

You might have preferred a reference, though. Your box classes do not look to me as if you really intended to copy them on each call to the print function:

```
void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box const& b);
```

Comment: Why can't you have `class Box;` + `class Box2 {...};` + `class Box {...{` + `void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box box) { ... }` ? (all in one file)? (Hint: you can.)

Comment: So, I forward-declared Box2 class in Box.h and forward-declared Box class in Box2.h, then I have changed to friend void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box); in Box.h and void printBoxMeretek(Box const&); in Box2.h...then I have changed the implementation in Box2.cpp to void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box const& box). Do I understand it right? Because I have got this error,yet: include\Box.h|14|error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Box2'|
include\Box.h|4|error: forward declaration of 'class Box2'|

Comment: @Colossus You need to include Box2.h within Box.h to have the complete definition available. Pre-declaring Box in Box2.h is sufficient, though, but you have to include Box.h in Box2.cpp, too.

Comment: @MartinBonner,yes, I know that I can do it in that way, but I guess It is a clearer way of design to separate the classes. Maybe I'm wrong, but anyway...I want to solve this way,too. :-)

Comment: @Aconcagua, now it's working. :-) One more remark: I have forgotten to change the function declaration to the new, referenced one in Box.h [friend void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box const&)], it was my fault. Thank you for your help, I am going to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @Colossus Actually, the reference is not *necessary* - adopted my answer appropriately - still, the reference appears more correct to me for the specific use case...

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    //friend function from Box2 [...]
>    friend void printBoxMeretek(Box);
> ```

Because that is *not* the function from `Box2`.  Instead it is the declaration of a freestanding function in the global namespace `::printBoxMeretek`.

Instead what you need is:

```
    friend void Box2::printBoxMeretek(Box);
```

... but to make that work, you will need to define `Box2` first - so `#include "Box2.h"` at the top of Box.h.

The final wrinkle, is that Box2.h can't include Box.h (otherwise you have a circular include).  Fortunately you don't need to.  Instead of `#include "Box.h"`, just use `class Box;` which declares the class (so you can use it as a function argument), but doesn't define it (so you can't create variables of type `Box`).

So, Box2.h:

```
class Box;

class Box2 { 
public:
    void PrintBox(Box b); 
};
```

Note that I have elided include guards.  You want those.

Box.h:

```
#include "Box2.h"
class Box {
    int v;
public:
    Box(int v);
    friend void Box2::PrintBox(Box b);

};
```

Box.cpp

```
#include "Box.h"
Box::Box(int v) : v(v) {}
```

Box2.cpp

```
#include "Box2.h" // Always put "our" header first to check it includes everything.
#include "Box"    // Needed to define member function
#include <iostream>

Box2::PrintBox(Box b) {
    std::cout << b.v << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Box.h"
int main() {
    Box b(42);
    Box2 b2;
    b2.PrintBox(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua : No it doesn't.  It declares a member function which takes a Box (by value) as argument.  The corresponding *definition* does declare a function parameter variable ... and that needs the definition (not just declaration) of the class.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have received this error:...\Box2.cpp|14|error: 'box' has incomplete type|
include\Box2.h|8|error: forward declaration of 'class Box'|

Comment: Box2.cpp will need to include both Box2.h *and* Box.h.